# How to know whether the grid view scrolled to the end

Tags: qt, qml

I am using a grid view, which can scrolled from left to right. When click on each item in the grid view, new screen launches with an animation from the current grid item position to the screen width and screen height. When click on the 2nd column elements after the grid view scrolled to right, the grid item position is getting wrong. Is there any way to fix this ? Or is there any method to check whether the grid view scrolled to the extreme right ?

Am putting my code below :

```
      GridView {
                        id: featuresGrid
                        snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
                        clip:true
                        x: 135
                        y: 122
                        width:1650
                        height:485
                        cellWidth: 825
                        cellHeight: 160
                        flow: GridView.FlowTopToBottom
                        model:favouriteapp
                        delegate:featureGridTile
                        focus: false
                    }

    ListModel {
            id:favouriteapp
            ListElement {
                featureName: "media & radio"
            }
            ListElement {
                featureName: "phone"
            }
            ListElement {
                featureName: "climate"
            }
            ListElement {
                featureName: "navigation"
            }
            ListElement {
                featureName: "ambient lighting"
            }
            ListElement {
                featureName: "settings"
            }

            ListElement {
                featureName: "camera"
            }

            ListElement {
                featureName: "dynamic-i"
            }

            ListElement {
                featureName: "bluetooth"
            }


        }

   Component {
                id: featureGridTile
                Item {
                    id:grid_view_rect
                    width:featuresGrid.cellWidth
                    height:featuresGrid.cellHeight
                    Text{
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        text : featureName
                        opacity: 1
                    }

                    MouseArea{
                        anchors.fill: parent

                        onClicked: {
                            featuresGrid.currentIndex = index
                           //Goes to the next screen with the current clicked grid item X and Y position  

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example that fullfills the mcve standards? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve No references to unknown `downscaleFactors`, `utilObj` or `featureGridTiles`. I want to run your code, see you problem, and provide a fix to it, if I can. But I don't want to work relentlessly to get the example running at all.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: ok, I got it running now. Still I don't get, what should happen, once I clicked on an element. A new thing is supposed to appear, like the tile you clicked on is expanding? And you can't find the propper position to start from?

Comment: yes. That is  exactly what i want.

Comment: Thanks derM. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are the `mapFromItem` and `mapToItem` functions:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapFromItem-method-1

```
Item {
    id: rootItem
    anchors.fill: parent


    Rectangle {
        id: myRect
        color: 'red'
        width: 50
        height: 50
        // the + 0 * featuresGrid.contentX will force the binding to reevaluate when draged. Maybe you don't want that. Comment it out and try
        x: featuresGrid.currentItem.mapToItem(rootItem, 0, 0).x + 0 * featuresGrid.contentX
        y: featuresGrid.currentItem.mapToItem(rootItem, 0, 0).y + 0 * featuresGrid.contentY
        z: 1
    }


    GridView {
        id: featuresGrid
        snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
        clip:true
        x: 135
        y: 122
        width:1650
        height:485
        cellWidth: 825
        cellHeight: 160
        flow: GridView.FlowTopToBottom
        model:favouriteapp
        delegate:featureGridTile
        focus: false
    }

    ListModel {
        id:favouriteapp
        ListElement {
            featureName: "media & radio"
            soureIcon:"file:graphics/Icons/MediaIcon.png"
            feature:"Media"
        }
        ListElement {
            featureName: "phone"
            soureIcon:"file:graphics/Icons/Phoneicon.png"
            feature:"Phone"
        }
        ListElement {
            featureName: "climate"
            soureIcon:"file:graphics/Icons/ClimateIcon.png"
            feature:"Climate"
        }
        ListElement {
            featureName: "navigation"
            soureIcon:"file:graphics/Icons/NavIcon.png"
            feature:"Navigation"
        }
        ListElement {
            featureName: "ambient lighting"
            soureIcon:"file:graphics/Icons/ALIcon.png"
            feature:"AL"
        }
        ListElement {
            featureName: "settings"
            soureIcon:"file:graphics/Icons/SettingsIcon.png"
            feature:"Settings"
        }

        ListElement {
            featureName: "camera"
            soureIcon:"file:graphics/Icons/CamIcon.png"
            feature:"Camera"
        }

        ListElement {
            featureName: "dynamic-i"
            soureIcon:"file:graphics/Icons/dynamicIcon.png"
            feature:"Dynamic_I"
        }

        ListElement {
            featureName: "bluetooth"
            soureIcon:"file:graphics/Icons/Icon Bluetooth.png"
            feature:"Bluetooth"
        }


    }
}

Component {
    id: featureGridTile
    Item {
        id:grid_view_rect
        width:featuresGrid.cellWidth
        height:featuresGrid.cellHeight
        Rectangle{
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "white"
            opacity: 1
            border.color: 'black'
        }

        Text{
            anchors.fill: parent
            text : featureName
            opacity: 1
        }

        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent

            onClicked: {
                featuresGrid.currentIndex = index
                //Goes to the next screen with the current clicked grid item X and Y position
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what am looking for.

Comment: I am glad I could help you :-)